# Is there a simple way to turn usual files into WordPress plugin?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have made a css3 based light box, basically it applies css3 rules to certain DIVs and makes them pop out with animation etc. I was thinking into turning this into a wordpress plugin, but it turns out wordpress uses slightly diferent coding language for its plugins that I am not comfortable with. So I would like to ask if anyone knows any easy ways to turn usual html/css3 code into a wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML and JS are the same in WordPress plugins as they are everywhere else, but there are some (mostly PHP-based) conventions that a plugin needs to follow.

The central docs on writing plugins is in the WordPress Codex: [Writing a plugin.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

If that's too much stuff (most of it arguably won't apply if your plugin will work in the frontend only, and need no server-side coding) maybe take a peek at an existing WP lightbox plugin. You may be able to learn from them how they integrate into WP, or even copy parts of it.